# Not given reputation points for received upvotes

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

As you can see below, a few upvotes that I received didn't register. Any particular reason?

---

[image]

Comment: You have reached the daily maximum limit of **200** reputation points. You cannot achieve more that that. Check the screenshot below. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: And: Congratulations on that ;-)

Comment: @Joachim, I wasn't trying to boast! :/

Comment: I didn't think so. It was an entirely non-ironic congratulation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have reached the daily maximum limit of 200 reputation points. You cannot achieve more than that. Please read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

From [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

[image: 200 rep]

Answer (score 4):

Because the top of your screenshot shows "198", it appears you hit the reputation cap on that day. You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation each day (excluding accepted answers and bounties) – all other reputation gain on that day after you hit the cap isn't counted.

Comment: Kevin Y... You exist outside of Gaming.SE?!? ;)

Comment: Yes, yes I do. (Slightly.)

Answer (score 3):

You reached the reputation cap, which is the daily limit for the reputation you can gain; you cannot get more than 200 with up-votes. You can gain more than 200 with accepted answers, and bounties.